# How to compile an android project with select productFlavor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

I have added two flavors in my build.gradle file

```
    productFlavors {
      prod {
        //prod values
      }
      dev {
        //dev values
      }
    }
```

I can select a flavor I want while making a signed build. But I want to directly run and test on my device the prod flavor. It takes dev flavor by default. I am guessing may be alphabetical order.

Comment: http://inaka.net/blog/2014/12/22/create-separate-production-and-staging-builds-in-android/

Comment: i don't think it work alphabetically

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html this is a good example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open android studio, on the extreme left side there is something called 'Build Variants'. Click that and choose the flavour you want to run. Once you click, it will take some time to build the project. Once that is finished run the project as you do normally.

Answer (score 2):

You can select any defined flavor from "Build Variants" pane (left side at android studio)

Answer (score 1):

In the left side menu in your `Android studio` select options **Build Variants**. Click that and choose the `flavour` that you want to run.

[image]